Can one kill lice on Shabbat?
(Inspired by this comment by @Ari)
In [Shabbat 12a], a difference in opinions is brought regarding whether one may kill a louse on Shabbat. The discussion culminates in a debate between בית שמאי and בית הלל, the latter of which, as usual, rules leniently. Since we generally follow the ruling of בית הלל over בית שמאי, it seems the final Halachah is that one may indeed kill a louse of Shabbat.
Later on, in [107b], there is a law described against killing animals on Shabbat. Rashi claims that the reason for lice aren’t included in this prohibition, is because most animals reproduce normally, but lice spontaneously generate.
Considering modern research has proved spontaneous generation a myth, does the Gemarah’s ruling still apply?

I don't know why I read this as "lick ice"

its hard to kill lice

Lice can transmit dangerous diseases.

Y D J  I'v  never heard of a case (in modern developed countries, at least) where someone's life was at risk because of lice. I think its similar to mosquitoes in he sense that although they can transport dangerous diseases and they are the most deadly animal, in most of the developed world, your life is not at risk if you have a mosquito bite.

The פחד יצחק brings that question, and concludes that we do not. His reasoning is that, had חז״ל been exposed to modern scientific knowledge, they would have recanted their ruling that lice can be killed on Shabbat, and this would in the end be forbidden.
It appears that, at least according to him, we don’t follow Halachot that were based on a now-disproven misunderstanding of חז״ל regarding nature.

This is perhaps the most famous and widely discussed science-halacha question, and you self answered with a single loosely sourced position? Not impressed

@DoubleAA I only learned about this debate from reading the linked comment a few days ago. I found an answer from a significant source, so I put it here. If you have a more informed and comprehensive answer, please, go ahead and post it. I’ll gladly accept it.

Do you have a more precise reference to your source?
